# Waitress - Print exceptions/stack traces to console?

Tags: python, pyramid, waitress

How can one go about getting Waitress to print exceptions/stack traces of any and all errors to the console?

Right now, Waitress seems to swallow up any exceptions not in application code.

For example, I was working with some middleware code, and forgot to `import base64`. With Waitress, I had no idea of this error. Gunicorn for example, spits out a stack trace to the console.

Comment: Post your logging configuration.  I actually had to turn waitress logging off because it was reporting to much.

Comment: I have no logging setup. Exceptions that occur within app code do get printed to the console though, so Waitress is able to produce output. It just chooses not to display exceptions that it encounters when producing a response and instead, shows a (basic text-only) 500 error message in the browser.